Postgres SELECT Hostname and Pathname Only
I have a text column that has values such as this
    text2 (https://example.foo.com/url/path/site.js:1:44541)
    text2  (https://example.foo.com/url/path/site.js:1:44541)
    text2  https://example.foo.com/url/path/site.js:1:44541:1:25413)
    text2  (https://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js:2:172704)
    text2  (ttps://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js:2:173513)
    text2  https://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js:2:171673
    text3 (https://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js:2:171651)

I'm trying to extrapolate only the hostname and pathname from the above such that I'm left with:
https://example.foo.com/url/path/site.js
https://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js

I haven't been able to find or create a regex for precisely what I need.  Any help would be appreciated.

What Solution have you tried? Is text# always present or varies?

Maybe (https?://[^:]+) would work?

Text2 is unique.  There are no predictable characters in the first part of each line.

Does (https?://[^:]+) work or can you define what you need to match if not?

I want to match on all URLs (protocol + hostname + pathname) in a given text field.  There could be multiple URLs in a single text field.

All URLs have line/chars on them (whatever :1:44541 is)? (https?://[^:]+) works or does not work?

data
CREATE TABLE yourtable(
   column1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO yourtable(column1) VALUES 
('text2 (https://example.foo.com/url/path/site.js:1:44541)'),
('text2  (https://example.foo.com/url/path/site.js:1:44541)'),
('text2  https://example.foo.com/url/path/site.js:1:44541:1:25413)'),
('text2  (https://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js:2:172704)'),
('text2  (ttps://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js:2:173513)'),
('text2  https://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js:2:171673'),
('text3 (https://exampel2.fooo.io/unique/bundle.js:2:171651)');

remove text# from column with following
SELECT regexp_replace(column1, 'text\d+\s*', '', 'g') AS cleaned_column
FROM yourtable

then remove ()
regexp_replace(cleaned_column, '[()]', '', 'g')

then use to remove after :
regexp_replace(cleaned_column, ':\d+.*', '', 'g') 

or
select 
  regexp_replace(regexp_replace(cleaned_column, '[()]', '', 'g'), ':\d+.*', '', 'g') 
   from (
SELECT regexp_replace(column1, 'text\d+\s*', '', 'g') AS cleaned_column
FROM yourtable) a

then check left character is h ttp --> http
 case when left(cleaned_column,1)='h' then  cleaned_column
        else concat('h',cleaned_column) end 

solution
select 
  case when left(cleaned_column, 1)= 'h' then cleaned_column else concat('h', cleaned_column) end cleaned_column 
from 
  (
    select 
      regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(cleaned_column, '[()]', '', 'g'), 
        ':\d+.*', 
        '', 
        'g'
      ) cleaned_column 
    from 
      (
        SELECT 
          regexp_replace(column1, 'text\d+\s*', '', 'g') AS cleaned_column 
        FROM 
          yourtable
      ) a
  ) b


or more difficult
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN left(cleaned_column, 1) = 'h'
            THEN cleaned_column
        ELSE CONCAT (
                'h'
                ,cleaned_column
                )
        END cleaned_column
FROM (
    SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(column1, 'text\d+\s*', '', 'g'), '[()]', '', 'g'), ':\d+.*', '', 'g') cleaned_column
    FROM yourtable
    ) a


dbfiddle

This is a great solution if text was always present. unfortunately there are no known predictable characters in the line.  ultimately i want to pluck out all URLs from a text block.

@Gerg it works in that sitution.dbfiddle
